# Assign the value of a column with a chunk of another subject to a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Python pandas dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd;
data = {'col1': ['AK B C1', 'A', 'C D', 'AK B E'], 'col2': ['', '', '', '', '']};
df = pd.DataFrame(data);
```

I want to extract from column col1 the third group of characters (' ' is the separator) when 'AK B' in col1) and the result assign it to column col2.

Expected result,

```
col2 = ['C1', '', '', 'E']
```

Comment: Can you have more that 3 groups? If yes, do you only want the 3rd group?

Comment: No in the example

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['col1'].str.extract(r'AK B (.+)', expand=False)

df.loc[s.notna(), 'col2'] = s
```

Or:

```
m = df['col1'].str.startswith('AK B ')

df.loc[m, 'col2'] = df.loc[m, 'col1'].str.extract(r'AK B (.+)', expand=False)
```

Alternatively, using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'].str.extract(r'AK B (.+)', expand=False))
```

Output:

```
      col1 col2
0  AK B C1   C1
1        A     
2      C D     
3   AK B E    E
```